# Надо вывести сообщения из консоли в модальное окно (Python)

Tags: python, gui, pyqt5, нейронные-сети, keras

Здравствуйте! Помогите решить такую проблему.

Прога состоит из двух файлов: `main.py` и `net.py`
В первом файле реализован интерфейс. Можно вводить значения параметров через `spinbox`, `textedit`, `combobox` и т.д.
Во втором файле реализована нейронная сеть на основе библиотеки `keras`, которая принимает параметры из файла `main.py`.

В интерфейс я добавил кнопку “Запуск”, которая запускает обучение модели сети, то есть те функции, которые есть в `net.py`.

Обучение идет долго, минут 30-50, в течение которых в консоли нейросеть выдает сообщения о каждом выполненном шаге с указанием ошибки обучения, вот так:

```
epoch 1/100, metrics = [...];
epoch 2/100, metrics = [...];
…
epoch 100/100, metrics = [...]
```

Если в это время даже просто щелкнуть по окну программы с интерфейсом, окно зависает (не отвечает). По сути, весомый косяк.

Чтобы не выводить обучение (исполнение файла `net.py`) в отдельный поток, я хочу при нажатии на кнопку “Запуск” выводить модальное окно. Если я правильно думаю, это должно убрать подобный конфликт, так как главное окно будет недоступно, пока модальное не закроешь. Или нет?

В модальном окне хочу выводить те самые сообщения из консоли. 
Если надо будет прервать обучение, то можно будет нажать на кнопку “стоп” в модальном окне.
Если обучение завершено, надо как-то вывести диалоговое окно с соответствующим сообщением.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такое модальное окно. Пишу на `pyqt5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то примерно получается так вы создаете класс `QDialog` в котором присваиваете его к модальному диалогу при помощи функции [`exec`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec), после чего окно `QWidget` блокируется до тех пор пока вы не нажмете кнопку остановиться или не закончится расчет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.edit_number = QLineEdit()
        self.label = QLabel('Введите число')
        self.button = QPushButton('нажми для начала')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit_number)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def clicked(self):
        self.dialog = Dialog(self)
        self.dialog.exec()


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super().__init__()
        self.g = 1
        self.resize(400, 100)
        self.main = main
        self.label_dialog = QLabel()
        self.button_stop = QPushButton('Остановись')
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.function_stop)
        layout_dialog = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_dialog.addWidget(self.label_dialog)
        layout_dialog.addWidget(self.button_stop)
        self.setLayout(layout_dialog)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.select)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def select(self):
        self.i = int(self.main.edit_number.text())
        if self.g <= self.i:
            self.label_dialog.setText(str(self.g))
            self.g += 1

        else:
            self.reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', "Все сделано")
            if self.reply:
                self.timer.stop()
                self.main.edit_number.clear()
                self.close()

    def function_stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', "Расчет был прерван последнее "
                                                              "число было равно = " + str(self.g))
        self.main.edit_number.clear()
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Да, вы совершенно верно меня поняли! Благодарю за пример )) По сути мне надо выводить результат функции model.fit ( ). Как написано в документации Keras она возвращает "A History object. Its History.history attribute is a record of training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well as validation loss values and validation metrics values (if applicable)"

Comment: Twiss, может сможете еще раз помочь?

Все настройки сети, напомню, выставляются в главном окне (файл main.py). Здесь же описана функция start_net, которая передает эти параметры в net.py - в функцию, которая как раз активирует нейронную сеть.

Модальное окно modal.py я сделал. На нем разместил кнопку, которая должна запускать сеть. Привязал на кнопку действие self.btn_on_start.clicked.connect(Main.start_net). 

Жму - ошибки. На примере одного параметра:
self.lookback = self.spnBox_lookback.value()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'spnBox_lookback' 
В чем ошибка?

Comment: @Артур лучше задайте новый вопрос с примечанием на этот и добавьте код, потому что я не знаю за что у вас отвечает переменная `spnBox_lookback`

Comment: @Артур а так на скидку могу сказать что у вас переменная `spnBox_lookback` не содержит атрибут `bool` (т.е. `True` или `False`)